Unable to Rebind Keys in Mathematica in Windows 11?
I've updated my operating system from Windows 10 to Windows 11 recently. I installed the Mathematica 14.1 after that. The execution result of $Version is "14.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)".
I want to use ctrl+f as my shortcut for fraction. I've tried the method mentioned in this post, i.e., I've added the following into my KeyEventTranslations.tr file:
Item[KeyEvent["f", Modifiers -> {Control}], "Fraction"],

However, it seems that this method does not work as the find function has been invoked when I press ctrl+f in my Mathematica. I've recommended the following code in the MenuSetup.tr file while this still does not work (this works fine in my previous Win 10 and Mathematica 14.0 version):
MenuItem["&Find...", KernelExecute[If[CurrentValue["PluginEnabled"], FrontEndTokenExecute[InputNotebook[], "FindExpression"], FrontEndTokenExecute["SelectionSetFindEx"];FrontEnd`DialogOpen["Find.nb", True]]], MenuEvaluator -> "System", MenuKey["f", Modifiers->{"Control", "Shift"}]],

Is the inability to rebind keys a new feature of Windows 11 and Mathematica 14.1, or am I missing something?
```


@Domen Thank you so much. It solves my question.

Have you tried the method described in the Wolfram community blogpost https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/291312?p_p_auth=WOQfQX2Z ? Please note in particular my comment on the changes since version 14.1. I think it is very likely that it has to do with the new order structures.
